# Conditional Formatting Depending Upon Multiple Numbers

Tags: regex, google-sheets, match, extract, conditional-formatting

I have a column of values that are a number out of 10. So, it could be 2/10, 3/10, 4/10 and so on, all the way up to 10/10. To be clear, these are not dates, but simply showing how many questions the student answered correctly out of 10.

I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight them a certain color depending upon the score they got. For 9/10 and 10/10, I'm wanting to use a certain color, but it doesn't seem to be working with REGEXMATCH or with OR. Also wanting to highlight all scores that are 6/10 or lower. I know that I could make this work by applying conditional formatting for each and every score with **text contains** but the problem I'm finding is that it thinks it's a date.

Is there a way to match multiple scores out of 10 using REGEXMATCH?

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NpDrFOhyG8sJyj4_oCv-qdktRElVepl4TfUBhjnCr-E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 link appended to the end of the post

Comment: see your sample sheet the `Copy of Sheet1`

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select column and change formatting to `Plain text`

[image]

now you can use formula like:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1; "^9|10\/")
```

[image]